# Range Space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I'm confused with the concept of Range Space of a matrix. To my knowledge $v$ is in Range Space of $A$ if this holds true: $Av=w$. Can anybody tell me if the vector $(1,0,0)^T$ is in Range Space of matrix 
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
2 & 2 & 2 
\\ 1 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix} \,?$$ According to me it's in the Range Space of A, but it's not. $A$ has rank $2$.

Comment: The range of a matrix is not a vector. The range is a vector space. It's the space of all w's that can be reached by A, e.g. the space {A*v, with v in R^m} where m is the number of columns of A

Comment: It is true that the vector $[1\;0\;0]$ is not in the range of your matrix.

Comment: You have got the definition wrong. Given $w$, if there is some $v$ such that $Av = w$, then $w$ (not $v$) is in the range space (column space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that with "Range Space" you mean the [column space $C(A)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces) of the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$. As you correctly said, it is true that $\operatorname{rank}\; A = 2.$ This means that $C(A)$ can be spanned by any $2$ linearly independent column vectors. $\vec{\mathbf v} = (2,2,0)^T$ and $\vec{\mathbf u}=(0,2,2)^T$ are linearly independent. So, these $2$ column vectors span $C(A)$.

Now, if $(1,0,0)^T \in C(A)$, then it has to be written as a linear combination of the above $2$ vectors. So, we can take the equality:
$$\vec{\mathbf x} = \lambda \vec{\mathbf v} + \mu \vec{\mathbf u}$$
and check if we can find values $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb R$. Thus, we have the following system:
$$ \left\{\begin{array}{l}
2\lambda + 0\mu = 1\\
2\lambda + 2\mu = 0\\
0\lambda + 2\mu = 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
which has no real solutions. Thus, $(1,0,0)^T \notin C(A).$

Comment: Thank you very much it's exactly the same answer. I'm pursuing Master in Engineering and it's very disappointing I lack such basic skills that now I need during research work. Can you tell me any good book to grasp these concepts? I came to know about Linear Algebra by David and Linear Algebra has done right by Axler. Any comments pls? Thanks again.

Comment: @MuhammadSaadShafiqQadri I don't know the books you mentioned, so I cannot comment about these books. I have been studying *Linear Algebra and Its Applications* by *G. Strang* , which I think it is pretty extensive. Regarding to matrices,  *Matrix Analysis* by *Horn & Johnson*, would be a good option.